# Inflating a Menu from OnItemClick

Tags: java, android, menu

I am trying to inflate a menu from OnItemClick. I looked at the android developer website, and was able to inflate a toast using the first code below. However, when I try to replace it with a Menu Inflater, it does not work. Can you help me solve the problem? The first set of code is the toast inflater that works, the second set of code is the Menu Inflater that doesn't. The toast pops up when I click on an item, but the Menu will not. The program will no run, and says I have multiple syntax errors in the menu inflater. Though I cannot solve them.

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.carouseldemo.main.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);




    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio);
    mp.start();
    Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {    

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Welcome to Power Source International");

            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);

        }



    });




    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {



            final TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

            switch(position){
            case 0:
                txt.setText("Power Source International ");
                break;
            case 1:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
                break;
            case 2:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
                break;
            case 3:
                txt.setText("Power Source International.");
                break;
            case 4:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
            case 5:
                txt.setText("Power Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source International");
                break;
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
        }

    }
    );

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

This works correctly. However, when I try to inflate a menu instead of a toast, it does not. This is the code that does not work, and has syntax errors in the menu inflater. Not matter what I try to do, I cannot correct the code.

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.carouseldemo.main.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio);
    mp.start();
    Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        private Object v;

        public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {    

            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            }

        }



    });




    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {



            final TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

            switch(position){
            case 0:
                txt.setText("Power Source International ");
                break;
            case 1:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
                break;
            case 2:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
                break;
            case 3:
                txt.setText("Power Source International.");
                break;
            case 4:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
            case 5:
                txt.setText("Power Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source International");
                break;
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
        }

    }
    );

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

Any advice on this? Thank you in advance.

Updated Code:

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.carouseldemo.main.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio);
    mp.start();
    Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {    
            openContextMenu(view);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    });




    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {



            final TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

            switch(position){
            case 0:
                txt.setText("Power Source International ");
                break;
            case 1:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
                break;
            case 2:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
                break;
            case 3:
                txt.setText("Power Source International.");
                break;
            case 4:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
            case 5:
                txt.setText("Power Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source International");
                break;
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
        }

    }
    );

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

Update 2:

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
  }


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio);
    mp.start();
    Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {    
            openContextMenu(view);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    });




    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {



            final TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

            switch(position){
            case 0:
                txt.setText("Power Source International ");
                break;
            case 1:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
                break;
            case 2:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
                break;
            case 3:
                txt.setText("Power Source International.");
                break;
            case 4:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
            case 5:
                txt.setText("Power Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source International");
                break;
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
        }

    }
    );

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try moving your `onCreateContextMenu()` method to the root of your Activity so it looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //implementation
  }
  //rest of code
}
```

Then you are probably going to want something like this:

```
 public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {    
     openContextMenu(view);
 }
```

Note that this will pop up the Context menu as soon as the user taps on an item.

Comment: It was about to work, but now there's just one error. It says: "The method onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu, View, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo) is undefined for the type Object." How could I solve this? Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @LuluR are you still extending Activity? If you are, redit your question with the updated code, it's easier to figure out that way.

Comment: Yes, I am still extending Activity. I have posted the updated code.

Comment: @LuluR `onCreateContextMenu()` needs to be at the root of your `MainActivity` since that is the class that overrides. See my updated answer for what it should look like.

Comment: There are no errors, but now it is saying the application is stopping unexpectedly. However, I am going to go ahead and rate your answer as the answer since there are no errors. I just need to figure out why it says the application has stopped unexpectedly and won't run. I'm using a phone, not an emulator. Thank you for your time and your help, I really appreciate it. My last question would be any advice as to why the application stops before it starts running?

Comment: @LuluR The LogCat stack trace will say why. If you're in Eclipse, you can do `Window -> Show View -> Other -> LogCat`

Comment: I have updated the code once more to show what I have. Could you look at it one more time to make sure I have everything in the right place?

Comment: I got the App to open, but now no menu inflates when I click an item.

Comment: Hmm, maybe add `registerForContextMenu(view);` before `openContextMenu(view);`

Comment: Still nothing. The app runs, but when I click on the items nothing happens. Should I open this question in another post, since its getting to another subject?

Comment: @LuluR You probably should, I ran out of ideas for this. But I still say it's feasible, maybe someone else can see something we missed.

Comment: If you want to try and help figure it out, you can look at my new questions. And there may be some new info that you can use to help. Thanks again, I wouldn't have even gotten this far without you.